# FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE() in Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I am reading Sql server book and i read FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE() this function.

But i have little bit of confusion for that.

Please explain it with Example if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its described with examples in the 2012 beta docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Did you actually invest any effort in finding information on this yourself? Just googling it yields enough useful information if you ask me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the best blog that can make you to understand that:

[SQL SERVER – Introduction to FIRST _VALUE and LAST_VALUE – Analytic Functions Introduced in SQL Server 2012](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/09/sql-server-introduction-to-first-_value-and-last_value-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/)